# Executing a c program in php on windows

Tags: php, c

Can any one please tell me how to run(compile and execute) a c file in php on windows(windows 8)?

I know that using exec() i can execute a compiled file but how to compile the c file in php?

I am using xampp.
I have tried with exec() but its not working.

Comment: You compile it by running a compiler.

Comment: Can you add your sample code in this post ?

Comment: The way you would `exec` a compiled program, you can `exec` the compiler itself with proper relevant parameters

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to compile every time you want to run it. So you would typically compile it once on its own, no need for php, and then use it as you want it.

(You could certainly run the compilation command using `exec`, but I don't see the point, and I believe you are confused as well.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a source code given from web site, you must compile it, but it can't be done in php. You need a C compiler, for example gcc. Install gcc and from php you call

```
exec( "/path/to/gcc source_code.c" );
```